# Advice on working three three iframes and switching back and forth

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently working on a project where I have to switch between multiple iframes after every step and it is getting hard for me to maintain reusable functions. Every other step can have a different Iframe.

I tried using try and except for Iframes but I do not think it is a good idea.

So I have something like this before clicking on any button. Note - there can be a situation where there are no Iframes.

```
try:
    self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
    self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
except:
    pass

try:
    self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
except:
    pass
```

Is it possible to change it something like this? and define it in a function and just call the function and it will change to the proper frame?

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.Id("frame1"));
 //  or
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.Id("frame2"));
// or 
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.Id("frame3"))

//Now we will switch focus,
driver.switchTo().frame("frame");
```